# Create a dynamic proxy for a class without no-argument constructor

Tags: java, reflection, proxy-classes, javassist, cglib

I want to create a proxy for a class instead of an interface. There are answers describing use of cglib or Javassist for this purpose (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4449998/), but I've run into a wrinkle, as the class I am interested in proxying doesn't have a no-argument constructor, so `Enhancer.create()` throws an exception. Looking at Javassist `ProxyFactory` javadoc, it needs constructor arguments as well.

The obvious workaround is finding constructor argument types by reflection and passing an array of nulls/0/etc. but this won't work if the constructor throws an exception.

Are there better alternatives (perhaps using some other library)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Objenesis](http://objenesis.org/) which is implemented as a wrapper around several JVM specific classes. As a result, this library allows you to create an instance of a class without calling any of its constructors. However, using Objenesis is potentially unsafe since the JVM-specific classes are not portable or standardized. For this reason, libraries like Spring or Hibernate rather require a no-argument constructor.

Shameless plug: If you in generally looking for an alternative to javassist / cglib that is still actively developed, have a look at my library [bytebuddy.net](http://bytebuddy.net).

Comment: Ah, so I create a proxy class with cglib/javassist/ByteBuddy and then create its instance with Objenesis?

Comment: Yes. That's what you do.